# Possible to specify class without specifying __tablename__ in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a base class where id and url are specified for convenience.

```
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = session.query_property()


class CrawlableEntity(Base):
  """CrawlableEntity class for all entities crawled online.
  """
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  url = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Model(CrawlableEntity):
  __tablename__ = 'models'
  name = Column(String)       # Bobby Raffin
  looks = relationship('Look', backref='model')
```

I am getting the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Class <class 'CrawlableEntity'> does not have a __table__ or __tablename__ specified and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class.
```

Is this pattern possible in sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 15):

See [Abstract Concrete Classes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html#abstract-concrete-classes):

```
class CrawlableEntity(Base):
  """CrawlableEntity class for all entities crawled online.  """
  __abstract__ = True
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  url = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

Comment: *slow clap* how do you even know this??

Comment: Recent docs for an ancient answer: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_config.html#abstract